# Web Speech API works on Chrome, but in ionic app it doesn't. What are the differences and what changes can make it run on ionic 1 app?

Tags: android, webspeech-api, ionic-v1

I get the error while using Web Speech API on the device.

the following works on browser not on the device

```
if(chatMessage.bot_msg && chatMessage.text && chatMessage.text != '') 
  {
        var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(chatMessage.text);
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    }
```

And throws error

```
SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined
```

I want to know if there is a way we can get the support in the ionic 1 app itself.

I have used TTS cordova plugin. But would like to know the differences, and support for these features.

Comment: Please provide us your code.

Comment: The new SpeechSynthesisUtterance() line throws the error. It works on the browser, just not on device.

Comment: You can't rely on the web browser of the mobile users. When you want to be sure to be able to use TTS in a Ionic app, use a plugin like; https://github.com/macdonst/TTS

Comment: Thanks @JoeriShoeby but I do not understand why. Ionic wraps an instance of a browser, why can not I use all browser features then?

Comment: @Andrew Because you cannot ensure that the end user has a version of the browser that supports it. By using a plugin, you are calling native functionality of the device.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby that is the point that Ionic does not need a browser installed. It bundles one with the app together, as far as I understand

Comment: @Andrew Your statement is incorrect. I'd suggest you to read through the documentation of the Ionic Framework. https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/webview